# Create a tar.gz from an image file (Linux or Mac)

Tags: tar, gzip, img

Hi I have an img of a custom linux distro and I would like to convert it to a tar.gz file. (I am using Mac or Linux OS)

What is the most straight forward way to do it?

Thank you

Comment: You might be better off converting it to a gz file rather then tar.gz as that is easier to work with and you are only talking about a single file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert isn't quite what it does. You can compress the image into a tar.gz file with:

```
tar -cvzf linuximage.tar.gz linuximage
```

You can uncompress/unzip with:

```
tar -xvzf linuximage.tar.gz
```

Just replace `linuximage` with the actual filename or folder.

Comment: You might want to prefix this operation by mounting the image, writing a file full of zeros until disk is full (cat /dev/zero>del.me) then deleting said file. This will likely greatly increase the compression ratio because the unused space is all zero rather then unknown characters.